# bash scripting, handling spaces in filesnames in a for loop strange behaviour

Tags: linux, bash, shell, handbrake

help.  everything i've tried has failed.  I'm trying to fix up my video collection and lots of them have spaces in the names/etc  I want to transcode them and I've written the script below, but its failing.  2 of the filenames I'm using for testing are "13 Eerie (2013).avi" and "Ace.Ventura.When.Nature.Calls.1995.720p.WEB-DL.x264-mSD.mkv"

i have tried several things from using print0 on find to mangling the IFS.  any assistance would be appreciated.  This current version for some reasons separates everything on the e character

---

### convert.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

OUTDIR="./done/"
LOGDIR="./logs/"
BACKUPDIR="./backup/"

# deal with spaces
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n")

# pull all files except MP4 or scripts in the CURRENT DIR only
for FULLFILENAME in `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -iname "*.sh" -not -iname "*.mp4" -print`
do
    # extract the file extension
    filename=$(basename "$FULLFILENAME")
    ext="${filename##*.}"
    filename="${filename%.*}"

    # use handbrake to convert to x264
    HandBrakeCLI -i "$FULLFILENAME" -o "$OUTDIR$filename.mp4" -e x264 -q 22 -r 29.97 -B 64 -O 2>$LOGDIR$filename.log

    # move the original file to a backup
    mv "$FULLFILENAME" $BACKUPDIR
done

#restore the field separator
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Don't use command substitution of `find`
- Don't use for loop
- Use process substitution to get output from `find`
- Use `-print0` option and read using `while` loop
- Better to avoid uppercase variable names
- Use `bash` shebang

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

outdir="./done/"
logdir="./logs/"
backupdir="./backup/"


# pull all files except MP4 or scripts in the CURRENT DIR only
while IFS= read -r -d '' fullfilename
do
    # extract the file extension
    filename="$(basename "$fullfilename")"
    ext="${filename##*.}"
    filename="${filename%.*}"

    # use handbrake to convert to x264
    HandBrakeCLI -i "$fullfilename" -o "$outdir$filename.mp4" -e x264 -q 22 -r 29.97 -B 64 -O 2>"$logdir$filename.log"

    # move the original file to a backup
    mv "$fullfilename" "$backupdir"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -iname "*.sh" -not -iname "*.mp4" -print0)
```

Comment: [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) are relevant readings for the listed suggestions.

Comment: removed previous response, I did more reading on process substitution and I get the syntax now, but its not working with a redirection unexpected error

Comment: @JamesWilson: Use `#!/bin/bash` at the top as in edited answer.

Comment: @anubhava - you are my savior sir.  its weird that my sh links to bash but manually specifying it fixed it.  +1Beer

Comment: @anubhava Sadly, I cannot accept this, it only ran the 1st item.  but its a massive step in the right direction,  I'm going to do more reading and see if i can figure out why, but please do the same as you clearly have more bash knowledge than I

Comment: Run this command: `while IFS= read -r -d '' fullfilename; do echo "$fullfilename"; done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -iname "*.sh" -not -iname "*.mp4" -print0)` and check the output

Comment: yes, that does present both testing files, and when run in the media folder it lists everything (tested by using wc -l)  but when i ran it as a script, the 1st video was converted, then it exited as successful.

Comment: to add to the confusion, I comment out the HandbrakeCLI command and added a echo "Converting $fullfilename" and it acts like both, but when handbrake runs it seems to kick out.  this would elude to its a handbrake thing, not the script.  I'm accepting this as a solution.